# apostrophe-oembed youtube videos are broken

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Since a few days I am Facing an issue with videos embed using "apostrophe-oembed",
I get an 403 error in the network tab.
The videos worked before.
Does anyone know if youtube changed something?
When I query the video directly it works.
[image]

Kind regards
Gradlon

Comment: Please check out this issue in the core package and let us know if it's still not working: https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/2636. TLDR; you should simply need to install fresh dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Alexbea.
This did not work for me.
What I did instead was:

```
construct: (self, options) => {
    self.apos.oembed.oembetter.endpoints([
        { domain: 'youtube.com', endpoint: 'https://www.youtube.com/oembed' },
        { domain: 'youtu.be', endpoint: 'https://www.youtube.com/oembed' },
    ]);
},
```

Comment: Gradion, this is fine and it removes a step from the process anyway, but are you sure just using `npm update` does not resolve the issue for you? None of our projects that have received an `npm update` still exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i might know the solution to the problem try id instead of embed
"youtube player flutter: ^8.0.0"
It will be easier if you do it using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).